# Powershell: Can't update a registry path because it doesn't exist (but it actually exists)

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are running Coded UI tests on IE in Windows 8.1, and we're doing it through Visual Studio Team Services.  As part of our build, we run a Powershell script that disables the popup manager.  The code we use to disable it is this:

```
Remove-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows" -Name "PopupMgr"
New-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows" -Name "PopupMgr" -Value 00000000 -PropertyType "DWord"
```

When I create and deploy a build in Release Manager, running this generates the following error:

> The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: **Cannot find path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows' because it does not exist.**

(Emphasis mine)

I've logged onto the VM and looked at the registry, and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows` absolutely exists.  The only thing I can think of is that its value isn't a DWORD but rather a string -- the `PopupMgr` key has a Data value of "yes" rather than 1 or 0.  But that doesn't match the error message -- the error says it can't even find the path of the key, not that the value type is a mismatch.  Plus, the code removes the existing key before inserting a new one, so I don't even know how it would notice the mismatch.

Even weirder, if I open Powershell inside the VM and run those exact two lines (I copied and pasted to avoid typos), they ran just fine.

This script worked on Windows 10 perfectly and has for a while, so I'm unsure what's going on here.  The user is a member of the Administrators group, so I don't think it's a permissions issue.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I suspect ps is running under some other user context in that case (probably system), can you add `whoami` in your script right before the call to modify registry and verify the output is the expected user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are trying to add the *Registry key Property Value*
You need to test for the existence of the registry key. If the registry key does not exist, then you need to create the registry key, and then create the registry key property value.

You should create the path to the registry key, then specify the property name and the value you want to assign. This consists of three variables as shown here:

This should help you out:

```
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows"

$Name = "PopupMgr"
$value = "00000000"

IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath))
  {
    New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value `
    -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
  }
 ELSE {
    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value `
    -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when renaming values, so I understood that for values you can (need / should) just define them, so I stopped trying to rename these values and started to define them :)

Just try to use `Set-ItemProperty` to change, set and reset values ...

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\New Windows" -Name PopupMgr -Value 00000000 -Type DWORD
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√]  **[MS-Doc's | `set-itemproperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7)**

  [√]  **[SS64.com | `set-itemproperty`](http://ss64.com/ps/set-itemproperty.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped Duttas answer in an easy to use function:

```
Set_Registry_key -key "HKLM:\FULL\PATH\pad\pat\KEYNAME" `
                 -type String `
                 -value 'value'
```

Function definition:

```
function Set_Registry_key{
    # String REG_SZ; ExpandString: REG_EXPAND_SZ; Binary: REG_BINARY; DWord: REG_DWORD; MultiString: REG_MULTI_SZ; Qword: REG_QWORD; Unknown: REG_RESOURCE_LIST
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $key,
        [ValidateSet('String', 'DWord', 'ExpandString', 'Binary', 'MultiString', 'Qword', 'Unknown')]
        $type,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $value
    )
    $registryPath = $key -replace "[^\\]*$", ""
    $name = $key -replace ".*\\", ""
    if(!(Test-Path $registryPath)){
        New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
        New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType $type -Force | Out-Null
    }else {
        New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType $type -Force | Out-Null
    }
}
```